# AWS RDS Read Replica but with different storage class/type

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, read-replication

I have a master db in one region.. and I want to create a read replica of it in another region just for disaster recovery practices.

I do not want it to be that costly, but I want the replication to work.
My current master db has db.t2.medium.
My question is:

- What type should I keep for my read replica? Is db.t2.small fine for my replica?

Comment: Its impossible to answer. Depends on you load and how "busy" is your primary db. Only you know this.

Comment: @Marcin yes that I understand, thanks! However, is it possible that I keep a lesser storage type for a read replica than the master? It wont effect replication right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not have much effect as read replica (RR) replication is [asynchronous](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html):

> Amazon RDS then uses the **asynchronous** replication method for the DB engine to update the read replica whenever there is a change to the primary DB instance.

This means that your RR will be always **lagging** behind the master. For exactly how much, it depends on your setup. Thus you should **monitor the lag** as shown in [Monitoring read replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html#USER_ReadRepl.Monitoring). This is needed, because you may find that the lag is unacceptably large for the RR to be useful for DR purposes (i.e. large RPO).